# SQL Language Tree Hierarchy and/with Alternate Language Names

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am working on a language SQL table to help search results within a specific application my company offers. The application deals with many languages, and is in fact an archiving project for every language of the world (over 7,000 languages/dialects). We have correctly formatted the hierarchy of all 7,000+ languages within a .JSON that includes the Language Family, Genus, ect... that the specific language is categorized under according to Ethnologue. Example below:

```
{
    "siouan-catawban": {
        "Catawban": {
            "Catawba": "[chc] (A language of United States)"
        },
        "Siouan": {
            "Mandan": "[mhq] (A language of United States)",
            "Mississippi Valley-Ohio Valley Siouan": {
                "Mississippi Valley Siouan": {
                    "Chiwere-Winnebago": {
                        "Ho-Chunk": "[win] (A language of United States)",
                        "Iowa-Oto": "[iow] (A language of United States)"
                    },
                    "Dakota": {
                        "Assiniboine": "[asb] (A language of Canada)",
                        "Dakota": "[dak] (A language of United States)",
                        "Lakota": "[lkt] (A language of United States)",
                        "Stoney": "[sto] (A language of Canada)"
                    },
                    "Dhegihan": {
                        "Kansa": "[ksk] (A language of United States)",
                        "Omaha-Ponca": "[oma] (A language of United States)",
                        "Osage": "[osa] (A language of United States)",
                        "Quapaw": "[qua] (A language of United States)"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Missouri River Siouan": {
                "Crow": "[cro] (A language of United States)",
                "Hidatsa": "[hid] (A language of United States)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of the 7,000+ languages ~6200+ languages have alternate names that someone could call it. Just like above, we have also input these into .JSON format, except these are called by the 'iso' code (in the [ ] from the example above). Here is what the alternate names .JSON would look like for the languages listed in the example above:

```
{
    "win":{
        "altName": "Hocák, Hocak Wazijaci, Hocank, Hochank, Winnebago"
    },
    "asb":{
        "altName": "Assiniboin"
    },
    "dak":{
        "altName": "Sioux"
    },
    "lkt":{
        "altName": "Lakhota, Lakotiyapi, Teton"
    },
    "sto":{
        "altName": "Nakoda, Stony"
    },
    "ksk":{
        "altName": "Kanze, Kaw, Konze"
    },
    "oma":{
        "altName": "Mahairi, Ponka, Ppankka, Umanhan"
    },
    "osa":{
        "altName": "Wazhazhe"
    },
    "qua":{
        "altName": "Alkansea, Arkansas, Capa, Ogaxpa"
    },
    "cro":{
        "altName": "Apsaalooke"
    },
    "hid":{
        "altName": "Hinatsa, Hiraca, Minitari"
    }
}
```

How could I create a SQL table that would accomplish the following: Within my search bar on the application search for "Mississippi Valley Siouan" and every language under it in the .JSON would be the result | AND | if I searched for the alternate name "Apsaalooke" (that has the 'cro' iso code) the "Crow" language would be a result.

-This also has to work and not be too cumbersome to do for 7,000+ languages (over 14,000 lines in the full .JSON).

-For an example on how deep these languages go within the tree, there are 11 languages that are buried 17 levels down.

The way the current search works, I can search for the language "Arabic" however, none of the resources we offer in Arabic show up. Because Arabic is made up of region specific dialects, you can search for "Egyptian Arabic" and that would show up, but "Egyptian Arabic" does not show up under "Arabic". The SQL table from the full .JSON would fix that problem because of language hierarchy.

I understand it might require a few different tables but that is ok. The willingness to do the work is there, I just need to know how. SQL newbie by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I have time later to type out an example then I will, but you should check out Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties. It's an excellent coverage of the topic with some great solutions. http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Edition-Kaufmann-Management/dp/0123877334